# catch the copy/ paste event UIMenuController

Tags: ios, swift, uimenucontroller

Is there any way to catch the copy/paste event in UIMenuController? I want to set flags when user tap copy option in menu on UIMenuController.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In order to catch the copy/paste event you have to subclass each UI component where you'd like to catch it.

Simple example with UILabel is shown in [Make UILabel Copyable in Swift](http://stephenradford.me/make-uilabel-copyable/) post. If you use their final code, don't forget to assign SRCopyableLabel as a base class for UILabel in storyboard. Also, modify the required init method in SRCopyableLabel class like that:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    sharedInit()
}
```

Then, whenever a user taps on "Copy", for instance, the corresponding "copy" method from SRCopyableLabel is called and you can do whatever you want in there:

```
override func copy(sender: AnyObject?) {
    let board = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    board.string = text
    let menu = UIMenuController.sharedMenuController()
    menu.setMenuVisible(false, animated: true)
}
```